# Chrome is not sending if-none-match

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, xmlhttprequest, etag

I'm trying to do requests to my REST API, I have no problems with Firefox, but in Chrome I can't get the browser to work, always throws `200 OK`, because no `if-none-match` (or similar) header is sent to the server.

[image: Chrome request]

With Firefox I get `304` perfectly.

[image: Firefox request]

I think I miss something, I tried with `Cache-Control: max-age=10` to test but nothing.

Comment: Can you post your code you're sending the request with? Are you using vanilla js or some library?

Comment: Is the code relevant? is made from angularjs

Comment: @avances123: Do you have enabled option in Chrome `Disable cache(while DevTools in open)`?

Comment: nope, I have tried everything from stackoverflow....

Comment: I migrated to Restangular, which has builtin etag support, but nothing, chrome doesn't send any conditional request header...

Comment: Thank you @P̲̳x͓L̳  I was looking for two hours now, head-scratching, wondering why etag/if-none-match did not work in my app. I had this option turned on :-(

Comment: @P̲̳x͓L̳, you really should have sent that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ilter, Jack Desert already added same answer.

Comment: @P̲̳x͓L̳, a year later than your answer :) I meant, you should have sent that in an answer, instead of a comment ;)

Answer (score 21):

One reason Chrome may not send `If-None-Match` is when the response includes an "HTTP/1.0" instead of an "HTTP/1.1" status line. Some servers, such as Django's development server, send an older header (probably because they do not support keep-alive) and when they do so, ETags don't work in Chrome.

[image: Sample HTTP/1.0 server response source]

In the "Response Headers" section, click "view source" instead of the parsed version. The first line will probably read something like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` — if it says `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` Chrome seems to ignore any `ETag` header and won't use it the next load of this resource.

There may be other reasons too (e.g. make sure your ETag header value is sent inside quotes), but in my case I eliminated all other variables and this is the one that mattered.

**UPDATE**: looking at your screenshots, it seems this is exactly the case (HTTP/1.0 server from Python) for you too!

Assuming you are using Django, put the following hack in your local settings file, otherwise you'll have to add an actual HTTP/1.1 proxy in between you and the `./manage.py runserver` daemon. This workaround [monkey patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patch) the key WSGI class used internally by Django to make it send a more useful status line:

```
# HACK: without HTTP/1.1, Chrome ignores certain cache headers during development!
#       see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28033770/179583 for a bit more discussion.
from wsgiref import simple_server
simple_server.ServerHandler.http_version = "1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm using Django Dev Server and I was with the same issue.

Comment: @natevw, I am facing the same issue. Problem is when i refresh the tab, if-none-match is not seen in request header. But when i make another ajax request, i am able to see it. What could be the problem.?

Comment: @VibhavSinghRohilla That does not sound like the same problem then. Perhaps your browser is simply trying to help by not using cache when you refresh? Maybe you could file your own question with more details.

Comment: @natevw - my questrion link is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845674/etag-not-received-back-if-request-made-from-different-tab-or-page-refresh-or-cha

Answer (score 18):

Also check that caching is not disabled in the browser, as is often done when developing a web site so you always see the latest content.

Comment: I spent 30 mins investigating this - now I feel stupid

Comment: Wow, that was my issue too! With Dev Tools open, cache is disabled so the "if-none-match" is not sent (Firefox).

Comment: about:config , browser.cache.memory.enable was disabled in my firefox

Comment: how to check this

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem in Chrome, I was using `http://localhost:9000` for development (which didn't use `If-None-Match`).

By switching to `http://127.0.0.1:9000` Chrome<sup>1</sup> automatically started sending the `If-None-Match` header in requests again.

Additionally - ensure `Devtools > Network > Disable Cache [ ]` is unchecked.

<sup>1</sup> I can't find anywhere this is documented - I'm assuming Chrome was responsible for this logic.

Comment: `Devtools > Network > Disable Cache` saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: With the latest Chrome 88.0.4324.104 sometime I still see Chrome doesn't sent "If-None-Match"

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is not sending the appropriate headers (`If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match`) because the cache control is not set, forcing the `default` (which is what you're experiencing). Read more about the cache options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache.

You can get the wished behaviour on the server by setting the [`Cache-Control: no-cache` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control); or on the browser/client through the [`Request.cache = 'no-cache'` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome was not sending 'If-None-Match' header for me either. I didn't have any cache-control headers. I closed the browser, opened it again and it started sending 'If-None-Match' header as expected. So restarting your browser is one more option to check if you have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will also not send `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match:` header if the script/file is downloaded via another script using xmlHttpRequest or jQuery ajax method.

Only those are linked via  tag, will add these headers.